# CheckBoxPreference isChecked causes a FC in a preferenceActivity

Tags: android, checkbox, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference, ischecked

When I check if the checkbox is checked, I get a Force Close in the following code:

```
public class preference extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public static final String nwd = "nwd";
    private CheckBoxPreference nwd_pref;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        nwd_pref = (CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(nwd);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    ...
    if (nwd_pref.isChecked()){
       // do code
    }
    ...
    }
}
```

I found this example during searching but looks the same to me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add a logcat, or at least what's the exception, are you sure that `nwd_pref` is not null?

Comment: This was the problem due to an type. Thanks. Shall add logcat in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findPrefernece(..)` will "[Return The Preference with the key, or null.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)"  It looks like "nwd" hasn't been set yet.

Comment: It is indeed "null", this while it does work for my EditTextPreference.

Comment: So you can do a null check and then default it to checked or unchecked if it has not been set already.

Comment: Found it, there was a typo in my xml. Thx